# Proof of inequality regarding measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ and let $A_n$ denote a sequence of sets in $A$. Let $k$ be a natural number so that the sets $A_m, A_n$ are disjoint for two indices with $|m-n| \geq k$.

Proof the inequality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n) \leq k \cdot \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$.

Now here are my thoughts: I guess the case $k=1$ is trivial since $\mu$ is a measue it is also a pre-measure and hence the inequality is true for "=" by definition which implies "$\leq$". Using induction we can see it is also true for $k+1$ since

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n) \leq (k+1) \cdot \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)\leq (k+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)$
because due to the equality in the definition of the pre-measure the sum is also greater or equal than the union and the sum is also positive and $k+1$ is bigger than $1$ hence the inequality follows.

However this seems too easy to me hence I think I made a mistake or missed out on something. Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: The problem in this induction is that to prove it for $k+1$ we assume that $A_m,A_n$ are disjoint for all $m,n$ with $|m-n|\ge k+1\,.$ We do not know if this holds for all $m,n$ with $|m-n|\ge k$ which is a stronger statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sets
$$B_1=\{A_1,A_{1+k},A_{1+2k},...\}\\B_2=\{A_2,A_{2+k},A_{2+2k},...\}\\.\\.\\.\\B_{k}=\{A_{k},A_{k+k},A_{k+2k},...\}$$

We have that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$

With this notation we have that $$\sum_{n
=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu(B_i)$$
Notice that we may do this as all sets in each $B_i$ are disjoint. Now using that $$B_i\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \implies \mu(B_i)\leq \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$$ we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu(B_i)\leq \sum_{i}^{k}\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=k\cdot \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$$

Comment: Nice. I am going to remove the comment part because I believe I have addressed that in another comment just now.